# Python Selenium-send_keys() function is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python for web page automation.
However it seems like `send_keys` function is not working. 
it's not throwing any error or exception, however it's not able to set the value in text field.

I am able to identify the correct field, able to click and clear the field data as well, however `send_keys` not able to set the data (value)

I wrote the below script in python using pycharm tool:

```
tx_power = web.find_element_by_id("tx_power-3")
tx_power.clear()
#After this I don't see 50 in text field
tx_power.send_keys("50")
```

and the HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="tx_power-3" class="form-control" name="tx_power-3" value="21.00" type="text"/>
</div>
```

answers are appreciable, Thanks

Comment: can you remove the .clear() line and try. By default sendkeys will clear the text before typing

Comment: @Ramesh Can you consider sharing the url in-case it is a public url? Thanks

Comment: @santhoshkumar i have tried by removing .clear() function, but didn't work and one morething same script was working 1 month back, when i tried now with same script it is not working, can i know the reason?

Comment: @ChandaKorat, tracetrack were there but in that did not mentioned the description of the error.

Comment: @santhoshkumar sendkeys does NOT clear the text before typing by default.

Comment: @JeffC In Java, it's the default behaviour of sendkeys

Comment: @santhoshkumar thanks for the reply, i have tried same scenario with different setup its working fine.thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not allowed to comment on other's post so adding an answer -
Did you try adding wait() between clear() and sendkeys()?

Edited Answer -
Please try below code -

```
tx_power = web.find_element_by_id("tx_power-3")
tx_power.clear()
tx_power.send_keys(Keys.HOME)
tx_power.send_keys("50")
```

OR

```
tx_power = web.find_element_by_id("tx_power-3")
tx_power.click()
tx_power.clear()
tx_power.click()
tx_power.send_keys("50")
```

Comment: kapil i have tried with putting wait() command in between clear() and sendkeys(), but didn't work,

Comment: @Ramesh - I have updated my answer, please try it. Hope it will work.

Comment: I have tried with above both code and did not work. @kapil, the same is working before but now it is not working i don't no whether it will depend on browser and python and selenium version?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have tried same scenario with different setup its working fine.thanks

Comment: @Ramesh - Can you please accept my answer and vote up?

Comment: @Ramesh- At the left side of my comment, there are up and down icons. Just press up icon. Thanks